# Map list of tuples into list of second elements in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, tuples

I have:

```
List<Tuple2<String, String>> listOfTuples
```

I would like to have a list of second elements from each `Tuple2`

Eg.

```
[Tuple2('1','foo'), Tuple2('2','bar')]
```

to

```
['foo','bar']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy. You can use [Groovy' spread operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator) to extract a list of the tuple's second elements.

Consider the following example:

```
def list = [new Tuple2('1','foo'), new Tuple2('2','bar')]

assert ['foo', 'bar'] == list*.second
```